# Select Query to Get Unique Cells in Two Columns

Tags: sql, database, select, sql-server-2012

I have an SQL Server database, that logs weather device sensor data.

The table looks like this:

`Id DeviceId    SensorId    Value
1      1           1         42
2      1           1         3
3      1           2         30
4      2           2         0
5      2           1         1
6      3           1         26
7      3           1         23
8      3           2         1`

In return the query should return the following:

`Id DeviceId    SensorId    Value
2      1           1         3
3      1           2         30
4      2           2         0
5      2           1         1
7      3           1         23
8      3           2         1`

For each device the sensor should be unique. i.e. Values in Columns DeviceId and SensorId should be unique (row-wise).

Apologies if I'm not clear enough.

Comment: How do you decide which rows to remove?

Comment: Just what Tim answered, I needed unique "DeviceId + SensorId"-group.

Wow, my question seems so vague I'm thinking to delete it. Even though I did get my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to sum `Value` as your desired result suggest, so you just want to take an "arbitrary" row of each "DeviceId + SensorId"-group:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Id, DeviceId, SensorId, Value,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DeviceId, SensorId ORDER BY ID DESC)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT Id, DeviceId, SensorId, Value
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

This returns the row with the highest ID per group. You need to change `ORDER BY ID DESC` if you want a different result. Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e31b/2/0 (your result)

Comment: Brilliant! Instead of `PARTITION BY DeviceId, SensorId ORDER BY ID DESC` I was doing `PARTITION BY DeviceId ORDER BY ID DESC`.

I was stuck for hours! Thank you :D